# Estimate Xmax for power law heads

Tags: r, estimation, power-law

[poweRlaw](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/poweRlaw/index.html) is able to estimate the  $x_{min}$ and $\alpha$ for power law tails, but I need to estimate the $x_{max}$ and $\alpha$ for a power law head. Can I take the reciprocal for each data point, and estimate $x_{min}$ and $\alpha$ for the reciprocal distribution? Is there any issue with this approach?